# Dense subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the two subgroups

$$
G=\{m+n\alpha : m,n \in \mathbb{Z}\}\\
H=\{2m+n\alpha : m,n \in \mathbb{Z}\}
$$
where $\alpha$ is some irrational number. We choose representatives of $G+y, \text{ for all }y\in \mathbb{R}$ and denote by $C$ the union of those representatives.

> Let X =C+H, show that
> $\mathbb{R}\setminus X = C+H+1$ and $(X-X)\cap (H+1)=\varnothing$

I know that $G,H$ are both dense subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. Can I use this here ?

Would appreciate any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The density is not directly relevant. Observe that $G=H\cup (H+1)$ is a disjoint union by  irrationality of $\alpha$.  It follows that ${\mathbb R}=G+C=H+C \cup H+C+1$. To see this is a disjoint union as well, suppose that $h_1+c_1=h_2+c_2+1$ with $h_i \in H$ and $c_i \in C$.
Then $c_1-c_2=h_2-h_1+1 \in G$, so we must have $c_1=c_2$, which contradicts the disjointness  of $H$ and $H+1$. This proves the first statement $\mathbb{R}\setminus X = C+H+1$.
if $h_1

Similarly, to verify the second statement $(X-X)\cap (H+1)=\varnothing$,
suppose that $c_1+h_1-c_2-h_2=h_3+1$ and get a contradiction from
$c_1-c_2=h_2+h_3-h_1+1 \in G$ in the same way.